# Which apk should I use on Bundle tool

Tags: cordova, bundletool

I use bundle tool version 1.7.0 to extract apks from bundle file (.aab) after that it gave me a toc.pb and splits folder. On splits folder there are apks base.af,base.en, base-master.apk, base-master2.apk etc. but when i try to install it on my device it says app not installed but on bluestach version 5 it work. What do you guys think I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't extract the APKs manually. You should use bundletool to select the APKs that are appropriate for the device.

First, you create a JSON file with the device specifications, then you pass it to the `extract-apks` command of bundletool.

From https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool:

> ### Generate and use device specification JSON files
>
> bundletool is capable of generating an APK set that targets a device
> configuration specified by a JSON file. To first generate a JSON file
> for a connected device, run the following command:
>
> ```
> bundletool get-device-spec --output=/tmp/device-spec.json bundletool
> ```
>
> creates a JSON file for your device in the directory the tool is
> located.
>
> [...]
>
> You can then pass this JSON to the bundle `extract-apks` command, as
> described in the previous section.
>
> ### Extract device-specific APKs from an existing APK set
>
> If you have an existing APK set and you want to extract from it a subset of APKs that target a specific device configuration, you can use the extract-apks command and specify a device specification JSON, as follows:
>
> ```
> bundletool extract-apks
> --apks=/MyApp/my_existing_APK_set.apks
> --output-dir=/MyApp/my_pixel2_APK_set.apks
> --device-spec=/MyApp/bundletool/pixel2.json
> ```

Another shorter way would be to call the `install-apks` directly if you don't need to see the APKs before installing them.

See the [Deploy to a connected device](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#deploy_with_bundletool) section of the documentation.